# Using a function in another and having a hard time with a loop/argument

Tags: python, function, file, for-loop, arguments

There are 3 functions involved:

```
Obtain_events()
obtain_date(date)
obtain_day_year(month, day)
```

This list of lists is in the function obtain_events().

```
[['Musique', 'Shawn Phillips', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-24'],
 ['Musique', "L'avenue Royale fête l'été!", '2018-08-25', '2018-08-25'],
 ['Musique', 'Perséides musicales', '2018-08-03', '2018-08-03'],
 ['Musique', 'Gaétan Leclerc chante Félix et…', '2018-08-17', '2018-08-17'], 
 ['Musique', 'The Ring of Fire : a Johnny Cash Experience', '2018-07-21', '2018-07-21'],
```

I have to call obtain_date(date) in obtain_events() in order to change all date who are string as int. Now, the function obtain_date(date) already works and is in charge of taking a str in argument as 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I'm having trouble with the argument and how am I supposed to take each index that has a date and put them in my date argument(every sublist has 2 date). Now here's the code for every functions

```
def obtenir_events():

    evenement = open("evenements.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
    ma_liste = []

    for element in evenement.readlines():
        #return the list of lists.
        ma_liste.append(element.strip().split('/'))      


def obtain_date(date):

date_list = date[5:].split('-')
        month,day = date_list
        day = obtenir_day_year(int(month),int(day))
        # This function works as far as I can tell. I'm allowed to modify it,
        # but I don't see the point. 
        return  day    


 obtain_day_year(month, day)   

 date_reference = date(2017, 12, 31) 

 date_actuelle = date(2018, mois, jour) 

## works and I'm not allowed to modify it. It's in french but it works only if you
## import **from datetime import date**. It returns the days of the year as
## long as it's an int, and it's working since I'm using it in
## `obtain_date(date).`
return (date_actuelle - date_reference).days
```

So here's the problem:

I need the to be able to call obtain_date(date) in the same for loop that i used in obtain_events() to change all date in my lists of lists into int that return the days in the year. so for example if I enter '2018-01-01' in my list of lists it would be replaced by 1 and if I enter '2018-12-31' it would be 365. The function obtain_date(date) already take care of making it a int, so my problem is how do i call this function in obtain_events() so I can reach every index that has a date in my list of lists so i can replace them for the int. This is just a sample of my list of lists because my lists is actually a file.txt and it has actually 160 lines. But you get the picture.

P.S. I feel my problem is very easy to solve. I just think that I'm still struggling with calling a function in another and I'm also having trouble reaching index of all my sub_lists in my lists. So if you're not sure you understand my explanation just try and code something very simple that could show me how I could implement my function with the right index so I can reach them all in my loop.

Comment: You just need the month and year from each sublist? Will the dates alwasy be in the last index of each sublist?

Comment: Yes but theres event with 2 dates to convert

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your list is a:

```
a = [['Musique', 'Shawn Phillips', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-24'], ['Musique', 
      "L'avenue Royale fête l'été!", '2018-08-25', '2018-08-25'], ['Musique', 
      'Perséides musicales', '2018-08-03', '2018-08-03'], ['Musique', 'Gaétan 
      Leclerc chante Félix et…', '2018-08-17', '2018-08-17'], ['Musique', 'The 
      Ring of Fire : a Johnny Cash Experience', '2018-07-21', '2018-07-21']]
```

Now write a function to get the date of the year:

```
def get_date(a):
    try:
        a = [int(i) for i in a.split('-')]
        return date(*a).strftime('%j')
    except ValueError:
        return a
```

Now get the new list using the following list comprehension:

```
from datetime import date
b = [[get_date(i) for i in j] for j in a]
```

The output:

```
[['Musique', 'Shawn Phillips', '236', '236'],
 ['Musique', "L'avenue Royale fête l'été!", '237', '237'],
 ['Musique', 'Perséides musicales', '215', '215'],
 ['Musique', 'Gaétan Leclerc chante Félix et…', '229', '229'],
 ['Musique', 'The Ring of Fire : a Johnny Cash Experience', '202', '202']]
```

To just get the last two digits of the date:

```
a = '2018-08-24'
b = '-'.join(a.split('-')[1:])
print(b) # will return '08-24'
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but im not allowed to modify the function that returns the int of my date, i only have the right to call it.

Comment: Then use this b = '-'.join(a.split('-')[1:]) code to convert a = '2018-08-04' to b = '08-04'